# Manage secure request with Tokens (JWT?)

Tags: node.js, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt

I am developing app using Firebase,Node,Mongo,Swift.

Firebase responsible for register & login.
Mongo is used for saving user information to DB.
Node as the server is responsible for manage request from the client.
in Swift we writing the UI & Client-Side.

so I am asking for a way that I can using some Token to auth user requests.
currently every user can ask any request if the user sending his Id.
it's not very secured, I would like to Manage the request, That only authenticated & logged in users can ask for requests.

I thought on that way -> every logged in user have Token from firebase right? , so a user can send me the Token & id, And on the server side Node will check if the Token is valid through FireBase.

Thanks for any response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your users are signed in to Firebase Authentication, you can send their ID token to your Node.js server, and there verify that the token is valid. You'll use the Firebase Admin SDK for this, and initialize it with the admin credentials for your Firebase project, so that it can check for the correct scope of the token. Then your own server-side code can use the information in the decoded token to ensure the user is authorized to perform the request.

This process is documented in the Firebase Authentication documentation on [verifying ID tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens), so I recommend studying that.

Comment: Thank you, it is what i was looking for !.
Should i resend Token ID with every request? (from client to server)

Comment: That's what the Firebase SDKs do. Doing so allows your server side code to be stateless (with respect to auth state at least).